# I don't understand this extend assembly inline code in C

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly

here is a C function that used extend assembly code in it:

```
static inline uint
xchg(volatile uint *addr, uint newval)
{
    uint result;
    asm volatile("lock; xchgl %0, %1" :
                "+m" (*addr), "=a" (result) :
                "1" (newval) :
                "cc");
    return result;
}
```

I read [this codeproject link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15971/Using-Inline-Assembly-in-C-C) for learn how to use Extended Assembly in C code but I confused at this code. 
I don't understand something in this code :
1) where is `(newval)` used as input in assembly code ? (`%0` is refer to `(*addr)` and `%1` is refer to `(result)` right ? then `"1" (newval)` never used in the code (we never see `%2` in code). or I am wrong ? )
2) what is `"1"` in `"1" (newval)` in input operands ?
3) what is `"+m"` sign means in `"+m" (*addr)` ?

Comment: You're mostly right. Read more [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html)

Comment: I will read this. thanks

Comment: Much better tutorial [here](http://locklessinc.com/articles/gcc_asm/).

Answer (score 1):

All the answers of your questions about GCC `asm` can be from from [6.41 Assembler Instructions with C Expression Operands](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm) and [6.42 Constraints for asm Operands](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constraints.html#Constraints).